# Is $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |k|(1+|x-k|)^{-100}$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{|k|}{(1+|x-k|)^{100}}.
$$
Is it finite?

Comment: No. For $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is one term of value $\lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: As long as you have one denominator that can be made $1$ by a choice of $x$, the corresponding numerator is a lower bound for the sum for that $x$. As is, you can make the term for each $k$ have denominator $1$, so without changing the denominator, you need a bounded sequence of numerators.

Comment: @DanielFischer this is a great comment. Perhaps you might consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. (extra characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the denominators $(1 + \lvert x - k\rvert)^{100}$, you can always make one denominator $1$ by choosing $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the corresponding numerator is a lower bound for the sum at that $x$, so without changing the denominators - or making some numerators negative - you can only have a finite supremum if the sequence of numerators is bounded. In that case, the supremum is indeed finite.